# accessing FBSession token from html in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios6

I have an app that I want to integrate with Facebook. It is a hybrid app with a native part and a javascript part that is in a UIWebView. I would like the user to be able to be logged into "both" parts. What is the standard way of handling this? Does the facebook sdk 3.1 natively handle this? Do I need some way of passing it in the url that I instantiate it with? Can I access NSUserDefaults from javascript? Can I create a custom handler to get at it?

I googled but due to common nature of words wasn't able to find anything that addressed this. I did read that LinkedIn's hybrid app actually ran a local server for accessing user data. This is more than I want to do. Any help is appreciated and sorry if this is addressed by Facebook SDK but wasn't able to find id.

thx in advance